# Group membership locks - Territory Hierarchy updates & Sharing recalculations

Tags: locking

I read through the [Record Locking Cheat Sheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/record_locking_cheatsheet.pdf) to understand record locking concepts and have some follow-up questions:

- What can be the cause of Group membership locks with relevance to Territory hierarchy updates?
- Can Account child(opportunity/case/contact) object updates cause Group membership locks?
- When a highly nested territory hierarchy is updated, does the group membership lock occur due to the territory updates or the sharing recalculations?